# Equation for resistors in parallel

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors

Who can explain why an equation of parallel resistors gives back an answer of 54.5 Ω? I don't understand how to read 1 in a quantity of 1/100 + 1/200 + 1/300 or how to write it in a calculator.

[image]

Comment: Sum the current through each resistor and then work out what the effective resistance will be,

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "I don't know how to use my calculator" is not an Electrical Engineering question, even if the calculation being attempted is an EE calculation.

Comment: @brhans respectfully, I think the question was about reading the formula properly and applying it in the calculator.

Comment: @jonathanjo - same thing ... "I don't know how to translate this written formula into something I can punch into my calculator" is also not an EE question, even if the formula happens to be an EE formula.

Comment: @brhans just to put the opposing point of view: if there was complex arithmetic I'm sure we'd all allow it.  Just because it's a beginner question doesn't mean it's inappropriate.

Comment: @jonathanjo nope. Throw in some *cos*s and *arctan*s and *shin*s and *e*s and *j*s or whatever else you dream up - "how do I use my calculator to work out this formula" will still not be an EE question.

Comment: @brhans We clearly have different judgements about this.  I'll let the matter drop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what kind of calculator you have, you might write

```
1÷((1÷100) + (1÷200) + (1÷300)) =
```

Or

```
1/((1/100) + (1/200) + (1/300)) =
```

Most scientific calculators have an "inverse" key, which will look like one of these two: [image]

and you can do:

[image]

Or command line python:

```
$ python3 -c 'print(1/((1/100) + (1/200) + (1/300)))'
54.54545454545455
```

Answer (score 1):

Think about *conductance* (G), being the reciprocal of resistance (R). With resistors in parallel, their conductance values are simply added:

G<sub>t</sub> = G<sub>1</sub> + G<sub>2</sub> + G<sub>3</sub>

Note the similarity to the individual currents across each resistor. Since conductance is defined as I/U, and with U being constant, I is proportional to G.

If you then replace G by 1/R you get

1/R<sub>t</sub> = 1/R<sub>1</sub> + 1/R<sub>2</sub> + 1/R<sub>3</sub>

Answer (score 1):

For any parallel network, the currents going into each branch will add up to the total current delivered by the source. Thus, if Vin is the source voltage and Iin is the source current, Vin/Rin should be equal to Vin/R1+Vin/R2+Vin/R3. From this, you can easily get 1/Rin = 1/R1+1/R2+1/R3. Rin is the net resistance as seen by the source.

On the other hand, for series resistances, the voltages across the individual resistances would add up to the source voltage.

Comment: In the calculator, you can use 1/(100^-1+200^-1+300^-1) to get the answer. Remember to include the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

With a conventional calculator with a 1/x key (such as the Windows calculator), you only have to do this:

100 [1/x] [+] 200 [1/x] [+] 300 [1/x] [=] [1/x]

With a Reverse Polish calculator you would do this:

100 [1/x] 200 [1/x] [+] 300 [1/x] [+] [1/x]